# Restricting Access to Application(s) on Point of Sale system

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, permissions, application

I have a customer with two point of sale systems, a few workstations and a Windows 2003 SBS Server.

The point of sale systems are typically running QuickBooks Point of Sale and are logged in with a user who has restricted permissions / access (via Group Policy). Occasionally, one of the managers needs to be able to run a few additional applications -- including some accounting software.

I have created an additional user for this manager, allowing them to login and access the accounting software. The problem is, it can be problematic to switch users on the system, as QuickBooks takes a few minutes to close (on POSUser) and then reopen (on ManagerUser). If customers are waiting, this slows things down drastically.

Since the accounting software is stored on a network drive, it would be easiest if the manager could simply double click something, authenticate against the network drive / domain controller and then the program would launch. When they close the program, the session to the network drive would be lost and the program would no longer be accessible.

Is there any easy way to do this? Both users are on a domain and the system is Windows 7. I just don't want to require the user to switch back and forth. In a worst case scenario, they forget to switch back and leave the accounting software wide open.

One possible solution is via the usage of the runas command

> runas /user:domain\ManagerUser \address\to\network\share

Comment: What about having the manager RDP into one of the workstations from the POS machine? You get fast access to applications, no need to log off from POS machine, and closing the session is fast and secure.

Comment: @Nic Unfortunately, that would require a free/available workstation to RDP into. The client doesn't have many "spare" systems available. I could possibly have accomplished this via terminal services, but that would have required additional licenses / etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I completely forgot about the runas command via the command line:

> runas /user:domain\ManagerUser \address\to\network\share

Comment: Instead of answering your own question, you may want to just edit the question itself...

Comment: @Phil I retracted my answer for awhile to see if any better responses would show up. In this case though, I believe the answer which I discovered is the best way to accomplish this.